# Content-type of Word file from Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ms-word, content-type

I need to get a content of the Microsoft Word (.docx) file from Amazon S3. I am able to get the object, but the result is not exactly what I want, because it looks like Word file opened in Notepad. I tried to read .txt file and it works perfectly. I think the problem is a content-type.

I would like to ask two question:

1. Is it possible to get the content of the document as is in file @Amazon and how to modify my code do achive that?
2. Is it possible to get the content with formatting (colors, bold text etc.)? If it is, I would aprreciate some clues.

My Code:

```
public static string ReadObjectData(string keyName)
{
    string responseBody = "";

    //using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    using (IAmazonS3 client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client("key", "secretKey", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1))
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "bucketName",
            Key = keyName
        };

        using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: There is no code in the question that deals with opening the document, can you explain what you're doing that triggers the file to open in notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question regarding getting the object with content type. I think Michael's answer has some information to resolve the problem.

I just like to add some additional information while storing the objects in S3 bucket. The content type can be set in the meta data field when the objects are added to bucket.

If you are storing the objects and retrieving it later, please add the content type (Content-Type) in meta data. So that you can get the content type of the object when you read it.

This is the better approach if you adding and retrieving the object later.

```
doc     application/msword
docx    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

If you are reading the object added by someone else, you can request then to add the content type information (or) you need to derive it as mentioned in Michael's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct `Content-Type` for a `.docx` file is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

The Content-type being set incorrectly may cause a web browser to render the document incorrectly, but that isn't likely the problem, here.  Setting it correctly will have no impact on the bytes that are actually contained in `responseBody` if you are trying to read it from code.

You need a library that understands the internals of files in the `.docx` format.